# Changing the structure of an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array containing dictionaries like this:

This is my code: where the keys are objs are "ABC", "SKY" and the keys are "T-4112-561-560.ts", "T-4112-561-561.ts"

```
 array = [NSMutableArray array];

        [array addObjectsFromArray: keys];
        [array addObjectsFromArray: objs];

 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: keys forKeys: objs];

[myArray addObject:[dict copy]];
```

This is my output:

```
2015-09-07 10:25:21.329 XBMC Remote[1082:454537] myArray:
(
        {
        ABC = "T-4112-561-560.ts";
    },
        {
        SKY = "T-4112-561-561.ts";
    }
)
```

I need to get the output something like this:

```
(
        {
        Name=ABC; 
        value= "T-4112-561-560.ts";
    },
        {
        Name=SKY;
        value = "T-4112-561-561.ts";
    }
)
```

Comment: Where does 'Sky' come from?

Comment: Indeed; what's the key to this conversion?

Comment: @Paulw11  : those 'Sky' and 'ABC' are name of the channels. i have put those dictionaries in to an array. what i need it, i want to specify those dictionary values with some particular names as "Name" and "value"

Comment: I am asking because there is no "Sky" in your first block of data.  Should the second "ABC" actually be "Sky"?  You need to clarify how the data maps in your question.  The answer is probably that you will need to loop through your array and build the target dictionary, but you haven't provided enough information. You should also make an attempt and show your code, explaining where you have a *specific* problem

Comment: @Paulw11 : I have edited the question in detail. yes you are right. this is my first question and I'm totally fedup with this. Please help me to sort out this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways that you can achieve this, but essentially all are going to come down to looping through the array, extracting the dictionary values.  There are a number of convenience methods you can use, such as `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`  but in order to keep it simple, the following code uses simple `for` enumeration loops -

```
NSMutableArray *outputArray=[NSMutableArray new];


for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray) {
    NSMutableDictionary *outputDictionary=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *key in dict.allKeys) {
        NSString *value=dict[key];
        outputDictionary[@"name"]=key;
        outputDictionary[@"value"]=value;
    }
    [outputArray addObject:outputDictionary];
}
```

Comment: your code retrieve the output as something like this :
name = "T-4112-561-560.ts";

but what i need is:
name = "ABC";
value="T-4112-561-560.ts"

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Fixed that